# ActiveModel Serializer: access attributes as methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, active-model-serializers

How can I access the defined attributes in a serializer as a methods?

```
class Test < ActiveModel::Serializer 
  attributes :a, :b, :c
end

s = Test.new(Object)
s.a
```

I need this for delegation, it used to be available in version 0.8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attribute methods are no longer defined on the serializer, and must be explicitly accessed through object

```
class MySerializer
  attributes :foo, :bar

  def foo
    bar + 1 # bar does not work, needs to be object.bar in 0.10
  end
end
```

See https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/howto/upgrade_from_0_8_to_0_10.md#010-breaking-changes